# GKGameCenterViewController is dismissed unexpectedly few seconds after being presented on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, game-center

I created a game integrated with GameCenter - I use a leaderboard to keep track of user high scores. From the main menu I allow the user to visualise the leaderboard using the GKGameCenterViewController class, creating an instance of it and present it on screen calling the following method from my main ViewController:

```
#pragma mark - Game Center Methods

//This is called from ViewDidLoad
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    if (!localPlayer.isAuthenticated){
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
            if (viewController != nil)
            {
                //showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: is an example method name
                [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            else if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated){
                [[SettingAndScoreManager defaultManager]refreshHighScore];
            }
            else
            {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Unavailable" message:@"An error occured - please open the Game Center and sign in manually selecting the game from the apps available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];
            }
        };
    }
}

//This is called when the "Leaderboard" button is pressed in the main menu - please see video demo below
- (void)showGameCenter
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
       gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
       [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}

//delegate method to dismiss the GKGameCenterViewController
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Everything use to work properly - when the method was called (and this is allowed only if the user is already authenticated in Game Center) the Game Center VC appeared on screen showing the Leaderboard. For three days, however, when I've been trying to call the method the VC appears, but remains empty for a few seconds and then it is automatically dismissed without pressing anything.

At the beginning I thought it was a temporary problem of the Game Center but it has been an issue for three days now - I tried it on 3 different devices and I have the same problem. However if I open directly the Game Center app and search for my app in the list of available games I can visualise the leaderboard correctly.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Here's a demo I've uploaded on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-id_gyNmgs&feature=youtu.be) that shows the issue.

**UPDATE:** I've raised a ticket with the Apple Developer Technical Support and after several tests they didn't manage to find an answer and suggested to file a bug report, which I've just done. I'll update the question with the outcome.

**UPDATE:** The problem ID on the Apple Bug Reporter is 15955767.

Thanks.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a simple demo application which you can share, or perhaps a bit more code in a gist? What you shared looks fine, but it may be related to some project settings or other conflicting code.

Comment: @M0rph3v5 I've just updated my answer with all the relevant code and a video demo that shows what happens.

Comment: Please post the radar number so people can duplicate.

Comment: @LeoNatan - thanks for your comment I've added it to my answer.

Comment: 1.) The problem ID 15955767 doesn't seem to exist. Is that the correct ID???
2.) Also, I can confirm that the problem you describe and show on YouTube is in fact happening 'intermittently' on my app (iOS 7 only) too. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. And I am using pretty much the same code you are.

Comment: I have almost the same issue (and identical code). In my case the screen is also empty but it is not dismissed automatically like in your case. This started to happen when I moved the app to a group (for sharing leaderboards and achievements with the paid version of the app). I can still see things correctly in the game center app, but not within my app. I think it may be related to having moved the app to a group. Any news on this issue?

Comment: Let me add that, as most things with Game Center, these issues seem to be happening at random. I restarted the simulator, and now it works. On my device, which I also restarted, it now gives an error when I try to log in to Game Center... a very nice 'Could not get services from gamed. Please file a radar including GameKit logs, and any gamed crash logs. ERROR Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"'